# How to assign a value to a variable according to conditions

Tags: r, function, unique, records

I hope someone could help me or at least give me a good advice.
I have a large dataframe to store scientific papers (classified by Author/Year/Journal). Most of the scientific papers give me more records, so I am trying to write a function (until now without success) that return me a unique value (named n) that identifies the paper from which the record belongs.

Comment: Stefano, welcome to SO. Please provide us with a reproducible example and try to explain (and show) what you expect your output to look like. You should also show us what you have tried so far.  There are a bunch of really good examples of how to do this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating unique values, you could use the `digest` function from the `digest` package.
For example,

```
library(digest)
digest(c("Granger", "1987", "Econometrica"))
```

returns a unique MD5 string for a publication. `digest` is not vector-able, i.e. you have to use `sapply` or similar to calculate the id for each row of your data frame.

Comment: or, less robustly, just `paste` together the authors/date/journal to get an ID string.

Comment: you could also use `interaction` to make a unique id for combinations of columns: `with(d, as.numeric(interaction(Author, Year, Journal, drop=TRUE)))`

Comment: Hi everybody. I try the solution proposed by Matthew and it works very well!I supposed I was enough clear in my example, but next time I will provide all the necessary details.I appreciate all the tips!